# Why the ban command does not work dsharpplus?

Tags: c#, discord, bots, dsharp+

I am making a bot for discord with dsharpplus and now I am trying to implement a ban command but it does not work.

```
[Command("ban")]
        [Description("Ban user")]
        [RequirePermissions(Permissions.BanMembers)]
        [Hidden]
        public async Task Ban(CommandContext ctx, 
            [Description("User banned")] DiscordMember member, 
            [Description("How many days will ban take?")] int days, 
            [RemainingText, Description("Reason")] string reason)
        {
            await ctx.TriggerTypingAsync();
            DiscordGuild guild = member.Guild;
            
            try
            {
                await guild.BanMemberAsync(member, days, reason);
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"User @{member.Username}#{member.Discriminator} was excluded by the ADMIN {ctx.User.Username}");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"User {member.Username} cannot be blocked");
            }
        }
```

Can somebody help me? I men

Comment: _it does not work_ - how exactly does it not work?

Comment: it does not ban the user I test this command!

Comment: Hook up CommandError event and you should get a reason why it's not working. Most likely your bot doesnt have permission to ban

Comment: Yeah! Apparently, my bot does not have permission to ban members, though that was the first thing I did when I created the roles for the test server. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it! So, the code is perfect but you have to check10 times if you give permission to ban members to your bot.
And for anybody which is thinking this code does not work:
1.check if you gave the permission to the bot
2.the command is !admin ban    not !ban   .

I hope I helped you, although I was the man who needed help:))