# How can I ban a Discord server member using dSharp

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

Can somebody help me? I am new to dSharp
How can I make a command to ban somebody on my server?

```
 [Command("ban")]
    [Description("Bans a user")]
    [RequireRoles(RoleCheckMode.Any, "Owner", "Supporter")]
    public async Task Ban(CommandContext ctx, string reason)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I found another question about banning a user with d#+ not working, and the comments helped that user get ban working. That question and answer may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773616/why-the-ban-command-does-not-work-dsharpplus

Answer (score 0):

Get the Discord member and call BanAsync

Example

```
[Command]
[RequireUserPermission(Permissions.Administator)]
[RequireBotPermission(Permissions.BanMembers)]
public async Task ban(CommandContext ctx, DiscordMember member, [RemaningText] string reason)
{
    await member.BanAsync(1, reason);
}
```

Comment: what does [RemainingText] mean?

Comment: It'll give you all the text left, 
ex: if you use !ban @banane I dont like them
if you don't use RemaningText, reason will be "I"
if you take Remaining Text, reason will be "I dont like them"